How to stop Origin & 3D cursor from affecting my object
So I'm trying to fatten the middle vertex of this object, and before I messed with the origin & 3D cursor, they didn't affect when I fattened the vertex. But after the scaling(?) the vertex follows the origin & 3D cursor and I couldn't get them back.
P.S. sorry for my lackness in terms I'm still new to Blender & thanks a lot!!
left is before I messed around, right is after. 

In the image below I've circled a button, if you click on that there will be a dropdown, and in that dropdown you will see some options which determine where the selected thing's (in your case the vertices') Transform Pivot Point is, independent from the actual origin. If you set this to 3D Cursor and scale the vertices, it would look like the object on the right of your picture, but if you set it to Median Point then it would look like the object on the left.


Omg okay thank you so much!!!

@jrylim if this solved your issue could you kindly tick the checkmark to the left of this post under the vote buttons so we can close this question.

@jrylim Additionally a quick note, what you are actually doing is most likely using the Scale tool with shortcut S as samuel assumes in his answer, although in your question you say you "fatten" the vertices. However the Shrink/Fatten tool has the shortcut Alt+S and it will actually not use the 3D Cursor even if you had set it in the Transform Pivot Point menu.
